# Fwrite() & Fread() vs. Mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql, fwrite, fread

I'm no expert in this world so I can only imagine the ignorance in this question.

I'm looking to build a very simple form tool for a work project. That said, all content needs to remain locally on a mapped share drive. Rather than connecting a mysql database to my form, would I be able to get away with just reading and editting a local .txt file using PHP's fwrite & fread functions?

Comment: You could, but they're a lot more work then a database and require more resources. Plus, you'd need to make sure file locking's doing its job.

Comment: mysql's using files with fwrite/fread already anyways. you gain a LOT more from having a proper database, v.s. having to essentially replicate what mysql's doing yourself. but if you're not expecting multiple users, multiple parallel access attempts on your file, blah blah blah, then you can certainly go roll your own system.

Comment: If you're answering your own question, *do it in an answer*. Write up an answer that describes your solution and put it here; don't just edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not try [SQLite](http://talks.php.net/show/sqlite/3): you'll have the advantage of a text file (single file) but with the power of a real database.